# Wordpress check if post is in category then do this... using custom categories

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

Ok im not sure if I have worded the title right but basically I have posts in custom categories and I want to get the current post category and do something.

So for example: if current post is in tag_id 15, say 'your in the category vegetarian'

this is what im using:

http://www.example.com/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?action=edit&taxonomy=food_category&tag_ID=15&post_type=vegetarian

any help would be great, thank you

Comment: your question is confusing me. i can not decide, what you are talking about. you mentioned category, then you says `tag_id`, and if i check your link, i see, the `vegetarian` is a custom post type, and the category is `food_category`

Comment: yh sorry i may have worded it bad... basically i need to know if the current post is in food_category&tag_ID=15&post_type=vegetarian then 'do something'

Comment: then you can use the $_GET variables. `if ($_GET["taxonomy"] == 'food_category' && $_GET["tag_ID"] == 15 && $_GET["post_type"] == 'vegetarian') { //do something }`

Comment: this doesnt seem to work when I use it

Comment: where do you want to use it? on the dashboard?

Comment: I want to use it in single post

Comment: then you need to use wordpress built in functions like, `get_the_category();`, `get_post_type()` and `get_the_tags()`

Comment: so what would the code look like now, could you show me?

Answer (score 4):

WordPress has a built in function for this: `in_category( $category, $_post )` (used inside the loop):

```
<?php if( in_category( 'vegetarian' ) ): ?>
   You're in the vegetarian category
<?php endif; ?>
```

That's good for a specific use case. If you always want it to spit out your "You're in the [category] category" for every category, including future ones, you would use `get_the_category( $id )` like this example (inside the loop).

```
<?php
$categories = get_the_category( $id );
if( $categories ){
  // Assumes you just want the first category
  print 'You&#8217;re in the ' . $categories[ 0 ]->name . ' category';
}
?>
```